# Add multiple criteria in conditional formatting?

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, conditional-statements

```
=A1:A>10<100
```

I am trying to change the background color for any number in column A that is meeting these conditions, but nothing is triggering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try this formula out:

```
=(A1>10)*(A1<100)
```

- 

[image]